# Should I create a temporary_users table for verification purposes?

Tags: php, mysql

Hello my question is if it is better to have a temporary_users table in my mySQL DB for those users who did not verify by email their account yet. If a user is verified then his data is copied into the users table.

Otherwise, all users, verified or not, will be saved in users table where there will be a new column with a random number. When the user is verified, that value will erased meaning that he is ok to login.

In the future I will create a forgot password function with the same structure as you suggest me.

What is the best method to have ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store all users in a single table, and store validation/not-validated state with each record. Whether you add a `is_validated` column, or simply store a unique token and set it to `null` for validated users is up to you.

Duplicating an entire table for the sake of adding a single column of data is not a very good practice, and it will be unwieldy; You want to be able to find the user based on their login credentials, and tell them their account is not yet activated. To do this with two tables will require two queries.

Comment: I have read some tutorials/opinions through google that they use to have a different table. Can you please give me a reason for this? ( I can not even think of one reason why should I create a new table ) Updated: I got my answer verifying what I thought also. Thanks

Comment: Can you give a single reason *for* creating a second table? Why did the tutorials suggest you do this? I can objectively say that my way is less complex and better from a performance standpoint (fewer queries) while being no less secure.

Comment: I don't know, that's why I asked this. For me it's a "stupid" idea but I thought am I missing something here ?

Comment: The only reason I can think for creating a second table is poor understanding of database normalization. Many, many online tutorials should only be used as reference material at best, and completely disregarded at worst.

Comment: @meagar Following up on this question, the benefit I could think of the unverified users table for something like email is that this table could have multiple entries of the same email, however the users table will only have a single entry corresponding to an email. When a user verifies the account, the user will be added to the main user table with all other entries in the unverified user table removed. This will prevent unnecessary populating of the users table by multiple users trying to register with same email. Can you please tell me what kind of a structure to follow for this usecase?

Comment: @AnandSinghKunwar that makes no sense. You should only ever have one attempted registration for a given email address. If somebody tries to register with an email that is already in an unregistered state, you should either reissue the activation email or generate a new token and resend it, but you definitely wouldn't insert a new row with the already taken email in any case.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to use a column in your main table as a flag for "verified" and "not verified".

When the user registers, insert their info into the database and set the "verified" colunmn to something representational of "not-verified" like a 0.

Once they verify, update your verified column for that user account to something representational of "verified" like a 1.

It is a waste of resources and extra database queries to create a brand new table for temporary users when it is more efficient to simply have a column that represents the users status, like "verified".

You can take this even further and instead have a "status" column for each user. Create a key of values that represent the users state of being, for example:

0 - Created, not verified
1 - Verified
2 - Inactive / Disabled account
3 - Banned
etc..

This can all be controlled by using one column to control the state of the user. It is absolutely un-necessary to have a seperate table for one state of being when you can use one column on the record itself to control as many states of being as you want.